# autocorrelation of Ornstein Uhlenbeck process with drift

Tags: autocorrelation, stochastic-processes

The Ornstein-Uhlenbeck (OU) process

$dX_t = -\frac{1}{\mu} X_t + \sqrt{\frac{2\sigma^2}{\mu}} dW_t $

generates coloured noise with autocorrelation function $R(t) = \langle X_t,X_{t'}\rangle = \sigma^2 e^{-|t-t'|/\mu}$.

I would be interested in modelling a process $ Y_t = \alpha t + X_t$. After some searching, I came across the terms "OU process with drift" or "trending OU process".

Does anyone know what is the autocorrelation function of the process $Y_t$? Thank you!

Comment: Also asked on dsp.SE where it has already received an answer.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49235/ornstein-uhlenbeck-with-drift